# Is it possible to run the Windows 10 Command prompt on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

I'm running a Windows 7 Machine and wish to use it with my Windows 10 Batch file, however the colored text it uses does not support the Windows 7 Console (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line ). Is there any way I can run the Windows 10 CMD on Windows 7?

Comment: Short answer. No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way I can run the Windows 10 CMD on Windows 7?

The improvements made to the command prompt are baked into the kernel.

What you want isn’t possible.