# Upgrade cmd.exe in Windows Server 2012

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-server-2012

Is it possible to upgrade the old cmd.exe in Windows Server 2012 to the newer one that comes with Windows 10? I like the new one much better because it's easier to paste things into it.

Comment: Update to Server 2016 or Server 2019?

Comment: What you want is not possible

Comment: I guess I'll just have to stick with the old one then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run the Windows 10 Command prompt on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/1352268/is-it-possible-to-run-the-windows-10-command-prompt-on-windows-7).   While the duplicate asks about Windows 7, I still consider this question to be a duplicate, since the answer is the same.  The command prompt improvements are baked into the kernel itself